# Create file system file from file stored in Microsoft SQL database

Tags: php, file, hex, filesystems

The title sounds confusing, but I don't know how to describe it better.

I've been given the task to do a database migration from program A to program B.
Program A uses a MSSQL database and stores all its files in the database.
Program B handles files with stored in the "normal" way, meaning in the file system.

Now I have to extract, transform and download the database stored files to file system files with PHP, but I was unsuccessful in my attempts to convert them.

For testing purposes, I created a simple `.txt` file with the content `Test document for migration` and program A stores it like this in the database:

```
0x5465737420646F63756D656E7420666F72206D6967726174696F6E'
```

**What format is that, and how do I convert it to a normal `document.txt` file ?**

### Edit

Lot of thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos. This now does work with a stream:

```php
$query = "select top(1) DESCRIPTION, FILETYPE, DOCUMENT from dbo.Documents;";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->sqlsrv_conn, $query);
if (sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) {
    $document = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 2, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));
    $fileName = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
    $ext = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 1, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
    file_put_contents(
        $fileName . '.' . $ext,
        stream_get_contents($document),
    );
}
```

Now what is the most efficient way to do this with ALL the files? Do I have to execute a query for each and every row?

With PDO I could use `$stmt->fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC)` which gave me a nice array of assoc arrays with data inside.
`sqlsrv` has a similar function `sqlsrv_fetch_array` which is explained [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) and [docs.microsoft] with the following example:

```php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}
```

But as much as I could search, I couldn't find a way to loop over the result set without fetching it and then fetching each row individually with the stream and string type mixed. `sqlsrv_fetch_array` accepts only `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC`, `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` and `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH` and then the result set is already fetched, and I can't use `sqlsrv_get_field` to set the type of each field.
I can't be the first person ever that needs something like this, but I'm unable to find anything about it. Probably I'm searching wrongly, or I misunderstood a concept.

Comment: Why are you assuming it should be a txt file? It could be any binary format. I would assume there must be metadata elsewhere in the database (normally in the same table or a related one) which tells you the name and possibly the mime type of each file stored in there. Otherwise it's hard to see how the original application could be making use of the data either.

Comment: I created this text file myself, so I know it, but they have many different file types, you're right. And they do have the extension and name of the document as well as other meta data like the datetime and pagecount but I couldn't find the mime type.
But I found the solution, I'll write a post shortly

Comment: @SamuelGfeller the solution is wrong. That's not a "format", that's how SSMS displays binary data. Your data access library already has ways to do this. Specify your library and add the actual data access code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apologies for the unclear question. Maybe it's better if I share what I try to achieve, which is "convert" ALL the files stored in an SQL Server 2008 database (about 9 tables) to file system files. Preferably with PHP because I know the language, but a little script in any language would do the trick with any library. (If PHP, it must be able to run on Windows). 
How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
I tested multiple online tool to decode strings and find out what the encoding was.
Even tried `hex2bin()` but all the tools told me that it wasn't a valid hex string.

Until I stumbled upon [this](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) godsent tool which translated the invalid hex to a `?` but translated the rest of it which resulted in:

```
?Test document for migration
```

From then on it was easy to deduct that `0x` was the troublemaker. After removing it, the conversion works like a charm and I could "convert" even complexer files like `.doc`. Here is the code:

```php
file_put_contents(
    // 'DESCRIPTION' is the file name
    'files/' . $dbDocument['DESCRIPTION'] . 
    // 'FILETYPE' is the extension
    '.' . mb_strtolower($dbDocument['FILETYPE']),
    // 'DOCUMENT' is the document content hex encoded with prepended '0x'
    hex2bin(str_replace('0x', '', $dbDocument['DOCUMENT']))
);
```

Comment: There's no format to convert in the first place. What you posted is how your database client displays binary data, not text. Whatever data library you use has a way of reading binary data already

Comment: Well not odbc, apparently. I previously used "sqlsrv" as a library, and it retrieved the files with binary data decoded already. The issue was that for 20 files it needed 25s. ODBC needs about 5s for 20 files but they are still in hex format and then with the `hex2bin` above it decoded fast (a lot faster than sqlsrv) so I went with this option

Comment: For example [PDO has a doc page on Large Objects (LOBs)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server examples for PHP [show how to use LOBs with SQLDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#lob-example) and [PDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#lob-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! I tried the PDO LOBS already, but I couldn't make it work, but I'll try again with the links you sent. Do you mind if I contact you if I still have troubles ?

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer :P. But I do know that almost all problems have been encountered and solved before. More often than not, the trick is knowing how to ask the question (or google), and the name of the problem. Multimedia and document storage and streaming access was the hot new feature in the ... 2000s. Commercial databases had to offer it because customers demanded it. At the same time storage became cheap enough that everyone could have a document management system, which meant DBs handling lots of medium-sized files.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos. It appears that I don't know how to ask properly. Could you take a look? Noone answers to my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378902/php-retrieve-multiple-rows-with-stream-content-at-once-with-sqlsrv and http://reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/ok4st8/how_to_fetch_columns_individually_from_a/h55uqmb/?context=3. If the solution you posted here only works for one row and can't be used for the whole table, it's useless to my use case and I have to go back to SELECT *.  No issue if you don't know, though (but I'd love to know that you didn't abandon the question)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a format, it's how some database administration tools, eg SSMS, display binary data. The data is already binary and doesn't need to be converted.

Reading Large Objects (LOBs) as if they were numbers or strings is *really* slow though, caching the entire document in both server and client memory, even though the object won't be reused, and doesn't even need to be held in memory. After all, a `BLOB` in SQL Server can be 2GB and more. That's why almost all databases and data access libraries allow handling LOBs as file streams.

Microsoft's PHP doc examples show how to read LOBs as file streams both for [PDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#lob-example) and [SQLSRV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#lob-example).

Copying from the example, this parameterized query will search for a user's picture:

```
/* Get the product picture for a given product ID. */  
$tsql = "SELECT LargePhoto   
         FROM Production.ProductPhoto AS p  
         JOIN Production.ProductProductPhoto AS q  
         ON p.ProductPhotoID = q.ProductPhotoID  
         WHERE ProductID = ?";  
  
$params = array(&$_REQUEST['productId']);  
  
/* Execute the query. */  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
```

Instead of reading the entire picture as a single value though, it's loaded as a file stream :

```
$getAsType = SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY);  
if ( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) )  
{  
   $image = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0, $getAsType);  
   fpassthru($image);  
}  
else  
{  
     echo "Error in retrieving data.</br>";  
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```

`$getAsType = SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY);` specifies that the data will be retrieved as a stream.

`$image = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0, $getAsType);` retrieves the 1st field using the specified type, in this case a stream. This doesn't load the actual contents.

[fpassthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) copies the stream contents directly to the output. The picture may be 2GB but it will never be held in the web server's memory.

Comment: That worked! I tried one more time with PDO, but it returns a string (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913) and I had the same issue I face now with sqlsrv functions.
I added an edit with details but how can I do this the best to retrieve each row now?